# Vue test coverage with Jest only checks imports

Tags: testing, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I'm testing my  vue.js 2 project with `jest` and `vue-test-utils`, the test works fine, but I've a problem when I try to measure the coverage of `.vue` files.

The problem is that when I execute `jest --coverage` I obtain 100% of coverage in those files, but if i enter to inspect which lines are coverage I see only the imports have been checked for Jest coverage and the rest of the code No (You can see that in the second picture.)

[image]

[image]

If you need more info please leave me a commend. Thanks

This is my `package.json` (only relevant info):

````
"scripts": {
  "test": "jest --coverage",
 },
"dependencies": {
    "core-js": "3.20.3",
    "single-spa-vue": "2.5.0",
    "systemjs-webpack-interop": "2.3.7",
    "vue": "2.6.14",
    "vue-i18n": "8",
    "vue-router": "3.5.2"
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~4.5.19",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.19",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.3.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-junit": "^13.0.0",
    "jest-transform-stub": "^2.0.0"
}

And my `jest.config.js`:


    ```
const alias = require("./aliases.config");

module.exports = {
  moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "vue", "json"],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
    "^.+\\.vue$": "vue-jest",
    ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|jpg|jpeg|png|svg|gif|eot|otf|webp|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga|avif)$":
      "jest-transform-stub",
  },
  preset: "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest",
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/"],
  modulePathIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/"],
  testMatch: ["**/tests/unit/**/*.(unit|test|spec).js"],
  collectCoverage: false,
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    "<rootDir>/src/**/*.{vue,js}",
    "!<rootDir>/src/main.js",
    "!<rootDir>/src/set-public-path.js",
    "!<rootDir>/src/router/index.js",
  ],
  coverageDirectory: "reports/unit-reports/coverage",
  coverageReporters: ["text-summary", "html", "cobertura"],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    ...alias.forJest,
    "@divilo/styleguide-base-front":
      "<rootDir>/tests/mocks/styleguide-base-front.js",
    "@divilo/api-mfes-front": "<rootDir>/tests/mocks/api-mfes-front.js",
  },
  coverageProvider: "babel",
  coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
      branches: 80,
      functions: 80,
      lines: 80,
      statements: -10,
    },
  },
  reporters: [
    "default",
    [
      "jest-junit",
      {
        outputDirectory: "reports/unit-reports/tests",
        outputName: "junit.xml",
      },
    ],
  ],
};
````